# Posting Video shares to Linkedin personal accounts via REST api

Tags: video, linkedin-api, ugc

We have an application in production that publishes rich media shares on Linkedin via the Assets and User Generated Content REST api's, using Oauth2 tokens.

When the Oauth2 token is associated with an organization at Linkedin we are able to create shares with text, image or video content, however when the Oauth2 token pertains to a personal Linkedin account we are only able to create text or image shares - attempts to create Video shares return 401 unauthorized.

We request and receive the following scopes: 'r_basicprofile','r_organization_social','w_organization_social','rw_organization_admin','w_member_social','r_1st_connections_size'

The permissions error occurs when fetching the uploaded media status, and this api succeeds for an organization when the media is image or video, and for a person when the media is image, but returns a permission error only when the account is personal and the media is video.

The Vector Assets and UGC api docs don't seem to explictly include or exclude video content for personal accounts; wondering if the Linkedin api team clarify whether personal video shares should be supported or not via these api's? If not supported are there any plans to do so?

Thank you,

Comment: double check you have the right permission as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#permissions) (w_organization_social and/or w_member_social)

Comment: Yes we request and receive w_organization_social and w_member_social